# PHP Retrieving what has already been sent

Tags: php, header

Ok I know I can do this via javascript but was wondering if I have say this

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Specifics of Bronica SQAi 150/4 PS </TITLE>

<?
include('producttopads.html');
```

and html processes php can I get the title...

Any ideas.
Thanks
Richard

Comment: could you specify the question? I'm not sure what are you asking.

Comment: "Can I access the title of the current (enclosing) php page using the php script within an included page?" ain't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like just this will do it
ob_get_contents

Comment: ...but only if output buffering is enabled **before** the output is sent.

Comment: Yeah in my case this is exactly what I wanted. Seemed to do the trick anyway!
The other ideas will work but only if you are outside of the file. 
I guess there are lots of ways to do it but this was the best for me

Comment: I am curious how you set this up to make it work for you.  From your description of the problem, I can't figure out how this actually does what you are looking for in any (even somewhat) efficient manner.  Could you post the solution you used?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');

$title = $html->find('title', 0)->innertext;
```

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to do it is this:

```
$pageTitle = "Specifics of Bronica SQAi 150/4 PS";
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE><?php echo $pageTitle; ?> </TITLE>

<?
include('producttopads.html');
```

Then you can access the title using the variable $pageTitle.

The other ways of doing it will require you to wait until after the page is loaded to access the title which isn't going to work for your purposes as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DOMDocument API](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). It can parse HTML or XML documents for you.

Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( "<html><title>your_title</title></html>" );
$title = $dom->getElementsByTagName( "title" );
echo $title->item(0)->nodeValue; // your_title
```